# Followed Unity Quickstart Guide and Builds with no errors but is just a frozen screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I followed the cardboard unity quickstart guide on windows with a Pixel 2 phone and I have no build errors but when I run the scene instead of seeing an image for each eye that moves when the phone is tilted I just see what looks like a static version of the scene.

Comment: we're probably going to need a little more info in order to be able to help you. What else have you tried? Does everything work within the editor, is their a mock position provider you can attach to simulate the phone's movements within the Unity editor?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to double-check if Cardboard XR Plugin is checked in Edit>Project Settings>XR Plug-in Management>Android tab.
After the next build, I got a VR stereoscopic view on my phone that react to phone movement and rotation.